# Gitlab CI pass environment variable to docker build

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to use https://gitlab.com/ric_harvey/nginx-php-fpm as base Gitlab CI image with docker executor. But this image has many configurations eg. WEBROOT. I need this WEBROOT set to my own value. It is possible when run it in Gitlab CI?

I already try (won't work):

- **variables**: definition in gitlab-ci.yml
- setup variable WEBROOT in **before_script** in gitlab-ci.yml
- add environment variable WEBROOT in Gitlab UI -> project -> CI/CD -> environment variable

All seems to be too late, what i need is to edit start command for docker as:

```
docker run -e "WEBROOT=xxx" ...
```

.

```
image: richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.1.1

variables:
  WEBROOT: "/build/domotron/cloud/www" <- this wont work

before_script:
   ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
   - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

   ## Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
   - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

   ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
   ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
   ## without extra base64 encoding.
   ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
   - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null

   ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
   - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
   - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

   ## Setup git
   - git config --global user.email "email"
   - git config --global user.name "User"

   ## Use ssh-keyscan to scan the keys of your private server.
   - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
   - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
stages:
  - test

Codeception:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome
      alias: chrome
  script:
    - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    - php composer.phar install --no-interaction
    - php vendor/bin/codecept run
```

Comment: And where you want this to appear?

Comment: Gitlab CI build image container itself. I am looking for a way how to tell Gitlab i want send this environment variable direct to docker command when is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as you cant overload `entrypoint` for your builder image:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-image-keyword

> The Docker executor doesn’t overwrite the ENTRYPOINT of a Docker
>   image.

I suggest that you create your own image, based on `richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.1.1`, and use it for building.

You can prepend one step into your pipeline, where you prepare needed tools like your own builders:

**gitlab-ci.yaml**

```
stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - ...
prepare-build-dockers:
  stage: prepare
  image: docker:stable
  script:
    - export WEBROOT
    - build -t my-builder Dockerfiles
```

**Dockerfiles/Dockerfile**

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.1.1
```

Btw gitlab now supports custom docker registries, so having your own images for build/test/deploy is a good practice.

Comment: And what to do with this builded image?

Comment: You build an image with all necessary atributes/environment, so lets consider it well formed for your needs. Then on next steps ypu use your image instead of original. In further steps of ci just use my-builder instead of richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.1.1